# Иногда возникает ошибка при работе с List Java

Tags: java, list, динамические-массивы

Уважаемые мастера программирования, ломаю голову, мне это очень нравится, но до тех пора она не начинает от этого болеть! Вот-вот я совсем близок к своей ПЕРВОЙ игре на Java , хоть и примитивной, но эта радость своей первой "сложной" программы нарастает, много было проблем, многие решал простым гугло-поиском, и справочниками.

И вот настала новая проблема, от которой я совершенно не понимаю как избавиться:

Моя программа это как-бы игра ДУРАК с 3 картами, но не суть.

Программа четко заполняет массив объектами класса Card:

```
#Карты:0 Rank: 0, Suit: 0 ,Is trump:false  |_2_| ♠
#Карты:1 Rank: 0, Suit: 1 ,Is trump:false  |_2_| ♣
#Карты:2 Rank: 0, Suit: 2 ,Is trump:false  |_2_| ♥
#Карты:3 Rank: 0, Suit: 3 ,Is trump:false  |_2_| ♦
#Карты:4 Rank: 1, Suit: 0 ,Is trump:false  |_3_| ♠
#Карты:5 Rank: 1, Suit: 1 ,Is trump:false  |_3_| ♣
и.т.д;
```

Также здорово через Collections.Shuffle мешает карты:

```
#Карты:0 Rank: 0, Suit: 1 ,Is trump:false |_2_|♣
#Карты:1 Rank: 9, Suit: 0 ,Is trump:false |_J_|♠
#Карты:2 Rank: 8, Suit: 3 ,Is trump:false |_10_|♦
#Карты:3 Rank: 11, Suit: 3 ,Is trump:false |_K_|♦
#Карты:4 Rank: 2, Suit: 2 ,Is trump:false |_4_|♥
и.т.д
```

Колода из 52 карт (от 0 до 51)

Настал момент раздачи карты игрокам- то он раздает все правильно и программа завершается хорошо:

```
Начало инициализации игроков:
Карты игрока №1:
Карта №:0 |_6_|♠
Карта №:1 |_4_|♦
Карта №:2 |_K_|♣
Карты игрока №2:
Карта №:0 |_4_|♣
Карта №:1 |_J_|♥
Карта №:2 |_10_|♣
КОЛОДА КАРТ ПОСЛЕ УДАЛЕНИЯ КАРТ ИГРОКОВ: 46
СБОРКА УСПЕШНО ЗАВЕРШЕНА (общее время: 0 секунд)
```

Но иногда сборка с ошибкой, причем ошибка начинается во-время перемешивания колоды!:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 49, Size: 49
    at java.util.LinkedList.checkElementIndex(LinkedList.java:555)
    at java.util.LinkedList.get(LinkedList.java:476)
    at simplecardgame.DeckOfCards.DeckInit(DeckOfCards.java:185)
    at simplecardgame.SimpleCardGame.main(SimpleCardGame.java:25)
```

Помогите разобраться пожалуйста- почему то работает нормально, то выдает ошибку!

Вот код, который не работает, когда ошибка появляется при сборке:

```
        System.out.println("Начало инициализации игроков:");

    //Переменные для игроков
    int currentDeckP1 = 3;
    int currentDeckP2 = 3;
    int rndmX1;
    int rndmX2;

    //Карты игроков;
    List<Card> listOfP1 = new LinkedList<>();
    List<Card> listOfP2 = new LinkedList<>();
    List<Card> deathCards = new LinkedList<>();
    //Инициализация игроков:
    Player p1 = new Player(0,false);
    Player p2 = new Player(0,false);

    //Раздача случайных 3х карт для игроков:
    for (int i = 0; i < 3 ; i++)
    {

        Random rndNum = new Random();

        //Измнеение переменных, чтобы можно было удалить карту из колоды:
        rndmX1 = rndNum.nextInt(list.size());
        rndmX2 = rndNum.nextInt(list.size());
        //Добавление карты в колоду игрока
        listOfP1.add(list.get(rndmX1));
        //удаление карты из основной колоды:
        list.remove(rndmX1);
        //Добавление карты в колоду игрока
        listOfP2.add(list.get(rndmX2));
        //Удаление карты из основной колоды
        list.remove(rndmX2);
    }
```

Comment: Так у вас же четко написан размер коллекции - 49, а карт должно быть 52. Пересмотрите код, куда исчезают эти недостающие элементы. где у вас коллекция , которую вы перемешиваете? list.remove(rndmX1); - это с ней дествие? копайте в сторону удаления элементов.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы тут `rndmX2 = rndNum.nextInt(list.size());` получили случайное число 49. Элементов в списке 50.

Дальше удаляете `list.remove(rndmX1);` элемент. Там теперь 49.

А теперь пытаетесь взять элемент `listOfP2.add(list.get(rndmX2));` на 49 позиции.

Вот и ошибка.

Находите случайное значение `rndmX2 = rndNum.nextInt(list.size());` после удаления.

```
Random rndNum = new Random();

//Измнеение переменных, чтобы можно было удалить карту из колоды:
rndmX1 = rndNum.nextInt(list.size());
//Добавление карты в колоду игрока
listOfP1.add(list.get(rndmX1));
//удаление карты из основной колоды:
list.remove(rndmX1);

rndmX2 = rndNum.nextInt(list.size());

//Добавление карты в колоду игрока
listOfP2.add(list.get(rndmX2));
//Удаление карты из основной колоды
list.remove(rndmX2);
```

P.S. создавать `Random` каждый раз не рекомендуется. Создавайте один раз в глобальную переменную и сделайте её `static`.

Comment: Спасибо огромное!!! Видимо голова заболела так сильно ,что не смог логически понять о возможном совпадении рандома в двух числах, и неизвестном индексе , после удаления :-)

Решил проблему, по вашему ответу, уже 50 раз включаю программу ошибки все нет, все четко :-)

И совет с рандомом спасибо, учту , в этом "проекте" поправил :-)

Comment: @ВладимирВодов иногда полезно отвлечься на некоторое время, а то глаза замыливаются, если долго над одним и тем же работать.

Comment: Из-за белого фона в NetBeans после долгого кодинга- начинают плавать глаза... Это бесит, привык к Visual Studio Dark , но по C# литературы толковой нету дома, только КНОПОЧКУ ВСТАВЬ И БУДЕТ ВСЕ РАБОТАТЬ ОК, а так Java мне очень нравится, жалко только ДОСТУПНОЙ Ide в Dark стиле нет (

Comment: @ВладимирВодов у Eclipse есть Dark Theme.

Comment: В NetBeans тоже http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/52624/netbeans-dark-theme